# swig, python and wchar_t problem

Tags: python, macos, swig

I am new to the Python C binding swig and have been trying to solve this problem for a while now. I have an external C library (Example.c) that I would like to call from Python. I read Swig tutorial and able to generate the wrapper in no time. The problem now is that when I invoke the API and I got this:

```
>>> import Example
>>> dir(Example)
['Example_CreateConnection', 'trimmed to fit the screen']
>>> Example.Example_CreateConnection("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: in method 'Example_CreateConnection', argument 1 of type 'ExampleChar const *'
```

It seemed like it cannot find the type `ExampleChar`. The following is my swig file:

```
%module Example
%{
#include "ExampleSDK.h"
%}

%include "ExampleTypes.h"
%include "ExampleSDK.h"
```

ExampleTypes.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef ExampleTypes_H
#define ExampleTypes_H

typedef wchar_t ExampleChar;

#endif /* ExampleTypes_H */
```

ExampleSDK.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef ExampleSDK_H
#define ExampleSDK_H

#include "ExampleTypes.h"
void Example_CreateConnection(const ExampleChar *temp);

#endif /* ExampleSDK_H */
```

The following are the command lines being invoked to generate the wrapper:

```
swig -python -I. Example.i
gcc -c Example.c -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/
gcc -c Example_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I.
gcc -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -o _Example.so Example_wrap.o Example.o -L/usr/lib/python2.6/config/ -lpython2.6
```

Here is how the Example.c looks like:

```
#include "runetype.h" // for Mac wchar_t definition

#include "ExampleSDK.h"

void Example_CreateConnection(const ExampleChar *temp)
{
    //do nothing
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with it. I hope someone will be able to point out the mistake(s) I have done over here. Thank you.

Regards,

Chuan Lim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I used `wchat_t` with SWIG+Python I ended up needing to add something like:

```
%include "pywstrings.swg"
%include "pystrings.swg"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "typemaps.i"  

%fragment("SWIG_AsVal_wchar_t", "header", fragment="<wchar.h>") {
    SWIGINTERN int SWIG_AsVal_wchar_t(PyObject* p, wchar_t* c) {
        return SWIG_OK;
    }
}
%fragment("SWIG_From_wchar_t", "header", fragment="<wchar.h>") {
    SWIGINTERNINLINE PyObject* SWIG_From_wchar_t(wchar_t c) {
        return SWIG_Py_Void();
    }
} 

// Python -> C
%typemap(in) wchar_t const * {
  $1 = PyString_to_wchar_t($input);
}

// C -> Python
%typemap(out) wchar_t * {
  $result = wchar_t_to_PyObject($1);
}
```

in my Swig interface file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have moved on to CType due to the deadline I had a while ago. I am sure that it works and I am grateful for your help :)

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 12.04 and there is error: No declaration for wchar_t_to_PyObject, i can't find any information about this function or what is it...

Comment: @meteor I suspect this is outdated with SWIG 2.0 and more recent versions of SWIG.

Comment: I ve tested this with SWIG v3.0.5: it works if I ommit the Python-to-C and C-to-Python typemaps, keeping the %include and %fragment directives