# SWIG_AsVal_wchar_t identifier not found

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm having some issues with SWIG and wchat_t types, to reproduce the issue I got a little MCVE [here](https://github.com/brupelo/swig_wchar)

The problem is SWIG_AsVal_wchar_t is called but it's not defined anywhere.

I've tried following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995764/swig-python-and-wchar-t-problem) but for some reason didn't work for me

How could I solve this?

PS: I've also posted the issue on [github](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/823)

Comment: The fix worked great for me. I'm using SWIG 3.0.2, g++ 4.9.2, and Python 2.7.9 on Debian. I am aware of quite a few bugs that has been introduced in later versions of SWIG. Which versions are you using?

Comment: @Jens Munk I'm using `SWIG Version 3.0.10 - Compiled with i686-w64-mingw32-g++ [i686-w64-mingw32] - Configured options: +pcre` and `Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64) on win32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use wchar_t, you could include the interface `cwstring.i` instead of `wchar.i`.

This allows to build your sample with this modified `libsystem.i` :

```
%module libsystem
%include "cwstring.i" 
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}
%include "foo.h"
```

An other way is to include the missing fragment using the following `libsystem.i`:

```
%module libsystem
%include "wchar.i"
%include <typemaps/wstring.swg> 
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}
%include "foo.h"
```

Comment: Awesome, I've been looking for this answer for few days already :) . What's your recomendation for the next time I got stuck with a swig question? I ask you this cos it feels like OFCT's irc channel & mailing list are a pretty slow way to get answers about this awesome swig tool.